# Acomodar texto a la derecha de imagen

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, float

Necesito acomodar un parrafo de texto a la derecha de una imagen. Entiendo que puede hacerse de dos formas, tanto con float, como con Display inline block. Desafortunadamente no me estaria funcionando.

```
<main>
    <div>
        <img src="img/profile.jpg">
        <p id="text1">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, ex     corrupti. Adipisci ex quis enim labore, consequuntur explicabo facilis? Corporis culpa adipisci eos numquam officiis perferendis eum vero? Necessitatibus, a.
        </p>
    </div>
</main>
```

```
#text1{
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}
```

Segun he estado viendo, si el texto tiene 50 caracteres se acomoda perfectamente a la derecha, pero al superar los 300caracteres ya no.

Answer (score 1):

Te aconsejo que uses [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) o [CSS-Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Si bien la propiedad `float` puede funcionar, es una regla basada en los estilos de ***CSS2***, que fue hace mas de una decada y claramente hoy en dia presenta problemas de compatibilidad en algunos [navegadores](https://caniuse.com/?search=float) de dispositivos moviles, algo que Flexbox y CSS-Grid no.

Te dejo un articulo adicional del por que los [Floats nunca fueron diseñados para el diseño](https://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2004/07/17/floats-dont-suck-if-you-use-them-right/) por *Eric A. Meyer*:

Finalmente la solcuion a tu problema:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#text1{
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}

main div {
  display: flex;
}

main div img {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633113216317-d0bb16e34e3d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80">
        <p id="text1">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, ex     corrupti. Adipisci ex quis enim labore, consequuntur explicabo facilis? Corporis culpa adipisci eos numquam officiis perferendis eum vero? Necessitatibus, a.
        </p>
    </div>
</main>
```

Saludos !

Answer (score 0):

Proba así:

```
#text1{float: left;}
```